# GitHub Pages site - redirect from www

Tags: github-pages

I have github pages site. For example **mysite.github.io**. When I open **[www.mysite.github.io](http://www.mysite.github.io)** it doesn't work. I want both of them to work.

Is it possible to redirect **[www.mysite.github.io](http://www.mysite.github.io)** to **mysite.github.io**?

**[EDIT]**

1. I use free github account.
2. For more information read [About GitHub Pages >> Types of GitHub Pages sites](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages).

Answer (score 3):

Well, to the best of my knowledge, that's not possible.
Only github can do that if they want to. I don't think that it's in our hand to make this redirect. It simply throws a 404.

Instead of doing this, consider buying a custom domain from a domain registrar.
After that, you'll probably be able to redirect from **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** to **example.com**

You can go for godaddy, hostgator or any other domain registrar if you want to buy a domain for your project.

Answer (score 0):

What [@daman-arora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11844909/daman-arora) said is correct, that to redirect to `mysite.com` from `www.mysite.com`,but at first you will need to buy a custom domain.
 But I want to say that you still can redirect from `www.mysite.github.io` to `mysite.github.io` by this simple trick:

1. Create a new repository named `www.mysite.github.io`.
   [image: GitHub repository named 'www.mysite.github.io']
2. Then create an `index.html` file.
3. And then put the redirection code in the file:

**`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://mysite.github.io">`**

**Problems of redirection:**

- Very **old browsers** might not redirect to the page you want.
- And if you use **JavaScript redirection** on your page, then it will not be redirected if JavaScript is disabled in users device.

  **Solution:**
   You can add "`<a href="https://mysite.github.io">Please click here if you are not redirected</a>`" to your page, so that users can click on the link and can go to the site, if not redirected automatically.

Comment: I create repository with name `www.mysite.github.io` (`mysite` is name of my site). Then it says `Your site is published at https://mysite.github.io/www.mysite.github.io/`. I can redirect `https://mysite.github.io/www.mysite.github.io/` to `https://mysite.github.io/`. This is not I want. I think for GitHub Pages my repository `www.mysite.github.io` is a project site and repository `mysite.github.io` is user site. I think this is the reason why is not possible what I want.

Comment: Both `https://mysite.github.io/www.mysite.github.io/` and  `www.mysite.github.io` will take you to the same page. After turning GitHub pages on, open `www.mysite.github.io` in your browser and all the contents will be of `https://mysite.github.io/www.mysite.github.io/`.